# Leaflet popup closes upon URL change

Tags: react-router, leaflet, popup, react-leaflet, query-string

I have a map with a callback that updates the URL query params when there is a pan event (i.e. when you move the map around the URL will encode your new position: `...?lat=-96&lng=191`).

I have markers that open a pop-up when clicked.

The problem is that when I click on a marker the map pans to allow the popup to fit the screen (`autoPan : true`), which triggers the query params update callback, but now the fact that the URL changed closes the just-opened pop-up :(

I tried `autoPan : false` and also to remove the callback that updates the query params, the issue disappears if I do that. But keeping autoPan and updating the query params is a requirement.

I am using React-Leaflet but I would not think it makes a difference compared to the normal library. To update the query params I use React-Router replace method:
`history.replace({ search: qs.stringify(newQueries) })` which I believe doesn't cause a reload.

Why are the popups disappearing and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Have you tried setting [`closePopupOnClick`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-closepopuponclick) to `false`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't change the situation

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, root cause: `location.search`, a React-router prop containing the query params, changes with every URL update. This caused the top-level component `SingleMapPage` to update, which in turn updated all the child components.

The solution was to return false from SingleMapPage `shouldComponentUpdate` method when only the query param are the only change between the old and the new props.

Component hierarchy for reference:

```
ReactRouter ↴
  SingleMapPage ↴
    MapComponent ↴ 
      MarkerComponent ↴
        PopupComponent
```